# Android removing my apps notifications automatically

Tags: android, android-notifications

Android removes my apps notifications when it creates more than 3 notifications.

This is not happening on all the phone, I can't even reproduce this on the emulator.

It is happening with my Moto G5S Plus running Android 7.1.1.

The error I am getting in the log is

```
NotificationService: Suppressing notification from package by user request.
```

Comment: Probably it's some anti-spam feature in Moto Android skin. Why does your app need 3 notifications on the screen anyway? One notification per one app is enough, even GMail groups your unread mails into one big notification instead of creating three of them.

Comment: @pelya Actually, the app is a note taking app, that save notes in the notification tray. Also, a user can use notification actions to mark the tasks as complete, that is why I need multiple notifications for multiple notes.

Comment: Well, you will need some UI redesigning. Most phones simply do not have enough vertical space to display more than 5 notifications, so you need one or two notifications which you can expand or shrink. Anything more, and your app will be treated like a push ad service.

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned error comes if the user has disabled notification of the particular application,

to check weather notifications are allowed or not refer to this link
[checking if notifications are enabled for specific package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50906821/checking-if-notifications-are-enabled-for-specific-package)

Otherwise, you can manually enable notification of particular application from App Info settings