# checking if notifications are enabled for specific package

Tags: android, reflection, notifications, root

I'm developing a system application and I need to check from my application if a certain package has notifications enabled or not.

I've been triying this code:

```
public static boolean isNotificationEnabled(Context context) {

    AppOpsManager mAppOps = (AppOpsManager) context.getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE);

    ApplicationInfo appInfo = context.getApplicationInfo();

    String pkg = context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName();

    int uid = appInfo.uid;

    Class appOpsClass = null; /* Context.APP_OPS_MANAGER */

    try {

        appOpsClass = Class.forName(AppOpsManager.class.getName());

        Method checkOpNoThrowMethod = appOpsClass.getMethod(CHECK_OP_NO_THROW, Integer.TYPE, Integer.TYPE, String.class);

        Field opPostNotificationValue = appOpsClass.getDeclaredField(OP_POST_NOTIFICATION);
        int value = (int)opPostNotificationValue.get(Integer.class);

        return ((int)checkOpNoThrowMethod.invoke(mAppOps,value, uid, pkg) == AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED);

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return false;
}
```

The issue is that it is returning true all the time. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't believe that will be possible. As far as I know there is a private API for that but as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39832714/how-to-know-whether-notifications-are-enabled-or-not-for-an-application-in-andro not possible to check other apps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android 4.1: How to check notifications are disabled for the application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11649151/android-4-1-how-to-check-notifications-are-disabled-for-the-application)

Answer (score 0):

If your method gets `Context` of the target application (which you want to check if notifications enabled).

You can create `NotificationManagerCompat` instance based on this `Context` and check if notifications are enabled for that application:

```
public static boolean isNotificationEnabled(Context context) {
    return NotificationManagerCompat.from(context.getApplicationContext())
            .areNotificationsEnabled();
}
```

Comment: I don't get it...I don't think this is what I'm looking for

Comment: @Aldridge1991 did you try this approach?
What context do you pass as the argument to your method?

Comment: I don't know how could I obtain a Context for a different application...